# display API data in the format as in image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I am new to React and currently doing my first project. I have a data that I get from an API. Now I need to display the data in the format as in image. I know about the map function but I am unable to map the nested object in the same row.{

```
"data": [
    {
        "ks_ref": {
            "id": 7,
            "shelf_position": 1,
            "mapped_shelf_name": "Shelf A",
            "mapped_kiosk_name": "Kiosk 1",
            "mapped_shelf_basket_name_reference": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "basket_position": 1,
                    "mapped_basket_name_reference": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "mapped_basket_name": "B1",
                            "mapped_product_name": "ABC",
                            "available_product_quantity": 400,
                            "available_product_quantity_units": "Units",
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "basket_position": 2,
                    "mapped_basket_name_reference": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "mapped_basket_name": "B1",
                            "mapped_product_name": "XYZ",
                            "available_product_quantity": 400,
                            "available_product_quantity_units": "Units",
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
    }
]
}
```

[image]

This is my approach. I am not able to map the nested objects to the same row of the html table.

```
const [allMappingData, setAllMappingData] = useState([]);
setAllMappingData(res.data.data);
return (
    <div className="container-fluid" style={{ maxWidth: "1000px" }}>
      <div className="py-4">
        <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }} className="mb-3">
          {" "}
          Listing All Mappings
        </h2>
        <Link
          className="btn btn-outline-dark float-left mb-2"
          id="basketback"
          to="/home"
        >
          Back
        </Link>
        <Link
          className="btn btn-outline-dark float-right mb-2"
          id="addBasket"
          to="/mappings/kioskshelfmapping"
        >
          Kiosk-Shelf Mapping
        </Link>
        <Link
          className="btn btn-outline-dark float-right mb-2 mr-2 ml-2"
          id="shelfbasketmapping"
          to="/mappings/shelfbasketmapping"
        >
          Shelf-Basket Mapping
        </Link>
        <Link
          className="btn btn-outline-dark float-right mb-2"
          id="basketproductmapping"
          to="/mappings/basketproductmapping"
        >
          Basket-Product Mapping
        </Link>
        <div style={{ width: "100%", overflow: "hidden" }}>
          {/* <div style={{ width: "320px", float: "left" }}> */}
          <table className="table border shadow" id="AllMapTable">
            <thead className="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                  #
                </th>
                <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                  Kiosk
                </th>
                <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                  Shelf
                </th>
                <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                  Shelf Position
                </th>
                <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                  Basket Position
                </th>
                <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                  Basket Name
                </th>
                <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                  Product Name
                </th>
                <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                  Available Product Quantity
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                {allMappingData.map((item, index) => (
                  <React.Fragment
                    style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
                    key={index + 1}
                  >
                    <th className={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{index + 1}</th>
                    <td className={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                      {item.ks_ref.mapped_kiosk_name}
                    </td>
                    <td className={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                      {item.ks_ref.mapped_shelf_name}
                    </td>
                    <td className={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                      {item.ks_ref.shelf_position}
                    </td>
                  </React.Fragment>
                ))}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you put your approach so we can help you with it?

Comment: Hi I have added my approach to solve this issue. But I am not able to map the nested objects to the same row of html table.

Comment: Welcome @Raj123 - thank you for your question. It is unfortunately too hard to understand what your exact problem is. Please try to focus on parts of the assets which are relevant to understand your issue. You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to find more information on how to improve your question.

Comment: Yes , I will work on it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should parse your data to look as your table first, and then render it

```
const [allMappingData, setAllMappingData] = useState([]);

const parseData = (data) => {
  const parsedArray = [];

  data.forEach(({ ks_ref: item }) => {
    item.mapped_shelf_basket_name_reference.forEach((shelf_basket, index) => {
      shelf_basket.mapped_basket_name_reference.forEach((basket) => {
        parsedArray.push({
          shelf_position: index > 0 ? '' : item.shelf_position,
          mapped_shelf_name: index > 0 ? '' : item.mapped_shelf_name,
          mapped_kiosk_name: index > 0 ? '' : item.mapped_kiosk_name,
          basket_position: shelf_basket.basket_position,
          mapped_basket_name: basket.mapped_basket_name,
          mapped_product_name: basket.mapped_product_name,
          available_product_quantity: basket.available_product_quantity,
        })
      });
    });
  });

  return parsedArray;
}

setAllMappingData(parseData(res.data.data));

return (
  <div className="container-fluid" style={{ maxWidth: "1000px" }}>
    <div className="py-4">
      <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }} className="mb-3">
        {" "}
        Listing All Mappings
      </h2>
      <Link
        className="btn btn-outline-dark float-left mb-2"
        id="basketback"
        to="/home"
      >
        Back
      </Link>
      <Link
        className="btn btn-outline-dark float-right mb-2"
        id="addBasket"
        to="/mappings/kioskshelfmapping"
      >
        Kiosk-Shelf Mapping
      </Link>
      <Link
        className="btn btn-outline-dark float-right mb-2 mr-2 ml-2"
        id="shelfbasketmapping"
        to="/mappings/shelfbasketmapping"
      >
        Shelf-Basket Mapping
      </Link>
      <Link
        className="btn btn-outline-dark float-right mb-2"
        id="basketproductmapping"
        to="/mappings/basketproductmapping"
      >
        Basket-Product Mapping
      </Link>
      <div style={{ width: "100%", overflow: "hidden" }}>
        {/* <div style={{ width: "320px", float: "left" }}> */}
        <table className="table border shadow" id="AllMapTable">
          <thead className="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                #
              </th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                Kiosk
              </th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                Shelf
              </th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                Shelf Position
              </th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                Basket Position
              </th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                Basket Name
              </th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                Product Name
              </th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }} scope="col">
                Available Product Quantity
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              {allMappingData.map((item, index) => (
                <React.Fragment
                  style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
                  key={index + 1}
                >
                  <th className={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{index + 1}</th>
                  <td className={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    {item.mapped_kiosk_name}
                  </td>
                  <td className={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    {item.mapped_shelf_name}
                  </td>
                  <td className={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    {item.shelf_position}
                  </td>
                  <td className={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    {item.basket_position}
                  </td>
                  <td className={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    {item.mapped_basket_name}
                  </td>
                  <td className={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    {item.mapped_product_name}
                  </td>
                  <td className={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    {item.available_product_quantity}
                  </td>
                </React.Fragment>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```